# Align buttons in a card grid with variable text length (Material Design Lite)

Tags: css, material-design, vertical-alignment, material-design-lite

I am in need of help understanding the flow here, I am not yet fully experienced with web design. This is my portfolio and I am trying to make a grid with Material Design Lite components, I trimmed down Google's stylesheet a lot, so the size file is much less now anyway.

I would like every card to have the same height for image, for text, for title, and for button so they would all look aligned in the grid.

The best fix I have, and is currently the layout being used is by setting display inline grid, and trying to play with values. I could really use a hand.

Testable example is in : https://jjba.ddnsking.com

The structure of the card is something like this:

```
<div class='mdl-cell mdl-card mdl-shadow--8dp portfolio-card'>
  <div class='mdl-card__media'>
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class='mdl-card__title'>
    <h2 class='mdl-card__title-text'></h2>
  </div>
  <div class='mdl-card__supporting-text trn'></div>

  <div class='moreButton'>
    <a class='glowingSmall trn' aria-label="Read More" target='blank'>read-more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes titles are out of alignment:

[image]

Sometimes buttons are out of alignment:

[image]

Comment: Please check in github, i am unsure what to post here:  [GITHUB](https://github.com/Josep-Jesus-Bigorra-Algaba/MyPortfolio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the answer to the problem goes with :

```
.mdl-cell{
  align-content: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is almost the perfect solution in case anyone is also using Material Design Lite for the Web.